# Xcode swift - Background mode - Audio in AVPlayer when locked

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, avplayer

I have got an AVPlayer setup but I cant seem to get the video audio to continue to play when the phone is locked or on the home screen. I have edited the info.plist and enabled the audio background mode but I think need to add some code. Please could you help me out. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func WarmUp(sender: UIButton)
    {
        WarmUpVideo()
    }

    func WarmUpVideo()
    {
        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("132", ofType: "MOV")
        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)

        let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerViewController.player = player

        self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in playerViewController.player!.play()
        }

    }

    func playExternalVideo()
    {

}


    @IBAction func CoolDown(sender: UIButton)
    {
        CoolDownVideo()
    }

    func CoolDownVideo()
    {
        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("132", ofType: "mp4")
        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)

        let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerViewController.player = player

        self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in playerViewController.player!.play()
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 16):

I think you're missing the following code:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                          .setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
    print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        print("AVAudioSession is Active")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Add this to your viewDidLoad.

Typical 2019 syntax of the key line of code:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
```

In some cases you may want:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
```

---

You MUST add this **ONE** item in plist (one item only, beware of old examples);

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Which is:

[image]

NOTE: years ago you had to also add *UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend* - **DO NOT** add this today.

Comment: Awesome, it works, but I have a problem: If I lock the device it continues playing but if I go to background using home button it stops. Any advice here? Thanks for that!

Comment: You need to make sure that you enabled background mode for audio. Target > Capabilities > Background Modes > Audio, AirPlay..etc and Target > Capabilities > Inter-App Audio. Just enabled those both

Comment: Yes, those settings was added with no luck :( still plays when when screen locks but not when app goes foreground

Comment: For anyone lately is facing same issue , Thisshould continue working in background  , Kindly replace  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)       with  this  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers) . hope this helps

Comment: @IsPha here in 2019, it seems that is NOT necessary.  Using `.setCategory(.playback)` will make it work properly (1) when you click lock (2) when you dismiss the app.   (Your excellent suggestion is necessary if other things are also playing on the device, we'd have to read the doco for that detail!)

Comment: 1)it doesn't work; 2)why do you use nested try-catch?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution on Apple's Documentation. Additionally to the background modes, you need to set to nil the player in order to avoid auto pause.

Here's the link:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/playing_audio_from_a_video_asset_in_the_background

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding these values to `Info.plist`:
[image]